# Pandas and bs4 skip hyperlink in scraped table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape a table off of a MTG goldfish using pandas and bs4.Long goal is to text myself the movers and shakers list but I get 4 out of 5 columns but it skips and gives an odd result for the one that has a hyper link. All i want is the displayed name for the hyper link so i can read it as a table

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


response = requests.get("https://www.mtggoldfish.com/movers/paper/standard")
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")


table = soup.find_all('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

The out put is this

```
 Top Winners Top Winners.1  ... Top Winners.3 Top Winners.4
0         5.49          xznr  ...       $ 16.00          +52%
1         0.96           thb  ...       $ 18.99           +5%
2         0.63          xznr  ...        $ 5.46          +13%
3         0.49           m21  ...        $ 4.99          +11%
4         0.41          xznr  ...        $ 4.45          +10%
5         0.32          xznr  ...       $ 17.10           +2%
6         0.25          xznr  ...        $ 0.71          +54%
7         0.25          xznr  ...        $ 0.67          +60%
8         0.15           eld  ...       $ 18.70           +1%
9         0.12           thb  ...       $ 11.87           +1%
```

The 3rd column is the name of the card attached to a hyperlink to the cards page on the site. I cant figure out how to extract everything together.

Comment: You can read data directly to pandas. Pandas will do the requests and Beautifulsoup for you in the background. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `.to_string()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://www.mtggoldfish.com/movers/paper/standard")
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all("table")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
   Top Winners Top Winners.1                   Top Winners.2 Top Winners.3 Top Winners.4
0         0.96           thb  Kroxa, Titan of Death's Hunger       $ 18.99           +5%
1         0.63          xznr              Clearwater Pathway        $ 5.46          +13%
2         0.49           m21         Thieves' Guild Enforcer        $ 4.99          +11%
3         0.41          xznr             Skyclave Apparition        $ 4.45          +10%
4         0.32          xznr        Scourge of the Skyclaves       $ 17.10           +2%
5         0.25          xznr                 Malakir Rebirth        $ 0.71          +54%
6         0.25          xznr                Blackbloom Rogue        $ 0.67          +60%
7         0.16          xznr                 Zof Consumption        $ 0.63          +34%
8         0.15           eld            Oko, Thief of Crowns       $ 18.70           +1%
9         0.12           thb             Heliod, Sun-Crowned       $ 11.87           +1%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read html tables directly to pandas. flavor can be set to "html.parser", but "lxml" is faster.

```py
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("https://www.mtggoldfish.com/movers/paper/standard", flavor='lxml')

# Daily Change
daily_winners = tables[0]
daily_lossers = tables[1]

# Weekly Change
weekly_winners = table[2]
weekly_lossers = tablke[3]
```